# mysql UPDATE says column cannot be null. Why is it null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a join table called `carriers_rects` that looks like this:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| carrier_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rect_id    | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I also have a `rects` table that looks like this:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default  | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL     | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(54) | NO   |     | new rect |                |
| width   | varchar(54) | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| length  | varchar(54) | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| rounded | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| xx      | varchar(54) | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| yy      | varchar(54) | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| height  | varchar(54) | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
```

I am trying to add a `case_id` column to `rects` and just make it a `one-to-many` relationship and kill the `carriers_rects` table. We are moving our DB and we never used the `many-to-many` relationship.

So I added the `case_id` column to `rects`:

```
alter table rects add case_id int(11) not null;
```

Then I tried to update the `case_id` on the rects with all the `case_id`'s that would match from the `carriers_rects` table.

```
update rects set case_id = (select carrier_id from carriers_rects where rect_id = id);
```

I am getting `column case_id cannot be null`.

I tested to see if there where any nulls and I can't seem to find any.

```
select * from (select * from carriers_rects where rect_id IN(select id from rects)) `b` where id is null;
```

I also tried it the other way around because honestly I am a little confused.

```
select id from rects where id IN(select rect_id from carriers_rects)
```

Clearly I am not a `sql` genius. But would love to be schooled here. 
Not sure why I am getting the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason of this error is in your inner query condition `rect_id = id` . They both are from `carriers_rects` (it means `carriers_rects.rect_id = carriers_rects.id`) so you get `null`. Change it to `rect_id = rects.id`

```
update rects set case_id = 
 (select carrier_id from carriers_rects where rect_id = rects.id);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error when I try that. Although it sounds like a great solution.

Comment: @Johnston  It means that you have some `rects.id` that doesn't exist in the `carriers_rects` table. You can use the JOIN syntax from @Rahul answer or add the condition to this UPDATE  - `WHERE EXISTS (select carrier_id from carriers_rects where rect_id = rects.id)`

Comment: Wouldn't my queries below test for that? That's what I thought too so I wrote those queries to test it and it does not sound like it has any.

Comment: @Johnston To test just use this query: `SELECT id FROM rects WHERE NOT EXISTS (select carrier_id from carriers_rects where rect_id = rects.id)`

Answer (score 5):

What if you change to a `update-join` syntax rather than using subquery like

```
update rects r
join carriers_rects cr on cr.rect_id = r.id
set r.case_id = cr.carrier_id
where cr.carrier_id is not null;
```

Comment: This does work! I still don't understand why mine does not work. But I am glad to have something that does work.